# Addition Using Stacks?

Tags: java, stack

I want to add a pair of numbers that are separated by a space. So a user inputs multiple numbers of any length separated by a space. I'm using BigInteger for this. Using two stacks,  each pair of numbers must be added together and the results need to be printed out. For example, the output would be like this:

10
+ 10
 = 20

99
 +  1
 = 100

1000000000000000000000000000000
 + 1000000000000000000000000000000
 = 2000000000000000000000000000000

I need to use stacks to do this. This is what I have so far but I'm not sure where to go after this.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Stack<BigInteger> stack = new Stack<BigInteger>();
    System.out.println("Please write some pairs of numbers to add separated by a space: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (BigInteger number : input.nextLine().split(" "))
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) 
        {
            stack.push(number);
        }
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            reverseInput += stack.pop();
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse an infix expression? or simply add the two operands? Maybe see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: No I'm just trying to add two pairs of numbers added by the user and print the results using stacks. Each number is separated by a space on a line inputted by the user, but only each pair will be added together and the results for each added pair will be printed. So for example, the user writes 10 10 30 40... the output would be 10 + 10 = 20.     30 + 40 = 70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need inner `for` loop. If you are trying to add two numbers using stack, you can push them into Stack, pop and add to the result, e.g.:

```
Stack<BigInteger> stack = new Stack<BigInteger>();
System.out.println("Please write some pairs of numbers to add by a space: ");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for (BigInteger number : input.nextLine().split(" "))
{

BigInteger result = new BigInteger("0");
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    result.add(stack.pop());
}
System.put.println("Result : " + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input.nextLine().split(" ");
```

returns a `String[]`, you cannot automatically cast it to `BigInteger[]`, as that will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Do you allow decimal values? If so, you'd be better off converting each `String` element to a primitive `double` representation, as you won't need the additional precision offered by `BigDecimal`.

As decimal values won't be allowed, you'd want to convert the `String` to its `integer` representation.

```
for (final String s : input.nextLine().split(" ")) {
   final int value = Integer.parseInt(s);
   stack.push(value);
}
```

The stack generic type will be `Integer`. So `Stack<Integer>`

Have you considered the case of bad user input? In that case you need to handle a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Decimal values would not be allowed.

Comment: @Srk93 I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
for (BigInteger number : input.nextLine().split(" "))
```

Isn't going to work, because that `.split()` returns an object of type `String[]`, and you can't directly treat `String` as`BigInteger`.

Also, you're doubling up on your for loops.  That line I copied above, *if* it worked the way you wanted, would loop through all of the numbers in your input.  So there's no need for that inner for loop.  In fact, it won't even compile, since `BigInteger` doesn't have a `.length()` method.

But you're on the right track.  What you can do is tokenize the input like you're already doing, and push each element into a the stack as-is.  Because there's no need to push them into the stack as `BigInteger`.  You can have a `Stack<String>`, and then convert them into `BigInteger` when you pop them back off to do the addition.  Or alternatively, convert them to `BigInteger` as you push each one onto the stack.